# Jquery random quotes with xml?

Tags: jquery, xml, flash

Can jquery interact with XML like Flash do. I want to make random text rotate with jquery and XML(text will be in XML file)

look at this http://healmyptsd.com/ left testimonials section in left under navigation bar. right now there are 3 images. I want to use selectable text and images in background for every testimonials. and the matter of testimonials should be in a XML file so client can add or remove easily.

Is this thing can be done with jquery or any other JS library? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. jQuery is good about consuming XML. See: [link](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032). I'd also look around, theres likely already a plugin available. However, I would actually suggest against this sort of tactic. You would be much better off doing this on the server and spitting the text out in the HTML for usability and search engine performance purposes

Answer (score -1):

Jquery is a shortcut wrapper for javascript so yes it can completely deal with XML. The user display functionality you are looking for, however, can only (to my knowledge) be done with CSS 3.0. Look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/css3-idea-rotation-of-page-elements/) to see how to do rotation effects in CSS 3.0